# How can I clone a window server-side using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs

I am currently running AngularJS server-side using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). It's working great, but I'm trying to optimize performance by caching the DOM generated by jsdom before the [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) scope is applied to the page. Trouble comes when I try to clone my cached DOM before applying the AngularJS scope for a given request. Currently, I'm cloning the cached DOM by using jQuery (server-side):

```
var clone = cachedWindow.$("html").clone(); // This part works fine
```

Then, I create a new window using jsdom with no content inside the html tag (fast):

```
jsdom.env(
  '<!doctype html><html></html>',
  injectedScripts, // This is where I inject AngularJS, which works fine
  function(errors, newWindow) {
    newWindow.angular.bootstrap(newWindow.document, ['ngView']);
    newWindow.$("html").replaceWith(clone); // This part does not work
  }
);
```

The problem comes from `newWindow.$("html").replaceWith(clone);` which generates this error:

```
{ code: 4, message: 'Wrong document' }
```

I understand the issue to be related to the fact that I'm trying to replace a DOM element within one document (`newWindow`) with a DOM element coming from another document (`cachedWindow`), but I can't think of any way around that. This is important, because cloning the `html` element is about ten times faster (literally) than rebuilding the DOM from scratch with jsdom...

Any suggestions?

Notes:

- On one hand, the solution I'm looking for needs to work with jsdom.
- On the other hand, I'm not married to jQuery. Any alternative would work just fine.
- Window cloning is required to prevent issues with concurrent requests and to support sessions.
- For more background, please check [CircularJS](http://sutoiku.com/tagged/circular) on Sutoiku

**Solution:**

Offered by [Jason Livesay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281920/jason-livesay), using [document.importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode)

```
var original = cachedWindow.document.getElementById("app");
...
var clone = newWindow.document.importNode(original, true);
newWindow.document.getElementById("app").appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I google that "Wrong Document" thing I see a bunch of PHP XML stuff that mentions importNode.  So maybe you can use that in JavaScript too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode

Or maybe something like this: http://jsdom.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/appendchild-problem-in-google-chrome-and-safari/

Also if you are looking to optimize that part, just to double check, you are saving the final HTML to disk right?  I mean you're not rendering the static page on every single request are you?

Comment: I am not saving the final HTML to disk. Instead, I am keeping the HTML DOM in memory, using a simple hash (one cached window per page). At every request, I lookup that cache, then apply the instantiated page model (aka AngularJS scope) before serving the resulting page. Therefore, the page remains dynamic, but most of the expensive part (HTML parsing and AngularJS bootstrapping) is avoided.

Comment: OK, sounds great, but if you know when the data changes, why not cache the whole HTML in memory once its rendered, and just invalidate that cache when the data is changed?

Comment: Because the resulting page is different at virtually every request, especially when requests are coming from different users, and the user's name is displayed on the page's header.

Comment: Jason, you rock! Your first link gave the solution. Thank you so much!